# Como mudar a cor do título da aba do navegador?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" a href="https://is.gd/DhDDsG">
<style>
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
<script>
    var titulo = "- 0wn3d bY 0xyrh0pus -"
var titulo = titulo + "          " 
i = "0"
var tmptitulo = "" 
var velocidade = "50"
const scrollTitulo = () => {
    if (!document.all && !document.getElementById)
        return
    document.title = tmptitulo + titulo.charAt(i)
    tmptitulo = tmptitulo + titulo.charAt(i)
    i++
    if (i == titulo.length)
    {
        i = "0"
        tmptitulo = ""
    }
    setTimeout("scrollTitulo()", 20)
}
window.onload = scrollTitulo
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=meta-theme-color

Answer (score 1):

> Como mudar a cor do título da aba do navegador?

**Não é possível**. O título é renderizado pelo navegador, logo, você teria  a pendência algum navegador que renderize algum tipo de estilização para a tag `<title>` no header, onde desconheço algum que realize.

Para reforçar o conhecimento. Trago uma tradução de uma [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649610/can-we-set-style-to-title-tag-in-header) feita no *stackOverFlow.com* sobre se é possível adicionar estilização de títulos dentro do header onde o [@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) cita:

"*Não conheço nenhum navegador que aplique CSS para a renderização do título nas guias do navegador ou nas barras de título*".

Answer (score 1):

Tente o 
`<meta name="theme-color" content="blue">`
mas serve apenas pra mobile.